# How to create global function on Coldfusion Flash Form page

Tags: coldfusion, actionscript-2

How do I create a global function that I can call from my actionscript code in a Coldfusion Flash Forms page. Currently, all actionscript functionality on the page is linked to an event, for example, how do I create a GetCustomDate method that can be accessed by both cfsavecontents below. Currently, I have to do whatever functionality is required for GetCustomDate in each cfsavecontent definition.

For example:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="OnCustomDateClick">
   var customdate = GetCustomDate();
   //do other stuff
</cfsavecontent>
<cfsavecontent variable="OnNewDateClick">
   var newdate = GetCustomDate();
   //do other stuff
</cfsavecontent>

<cfinput onClick="#OnCustomDateClick#" type="text" name="customDate">
<cfinput onClick="#OnNewDateClick#" type="text" name="newDate">
```

The code may not be 100% accurate but you can get the jist of what I'm trying to accomplish. I really hope there is a way to do this.

--- UPDATE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Ok, so based on the comments so far, we are almost there except for one thing: 
Please excuse that the code is a little more complex that the simple GetCustomDate example I gave previously. It was made simple to illustrate the problem.

Given the code below. 
When I try and call GetCurrency like so:

```
_global.GetCurrency('40346feb-feb9-11d8-995f-00c0df070000');
alert('Symbol After: ' + _global.GetMyResult());
```

The output is:

```
Symbol Before: $
Symbol After: Undefined
```

As you can see by the alert, the currencySymbol value ($) is set and accessible from within the GetCurrency method, but once it leaves that method, it's value is 'undefined'.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I have also tried returning the currencySymbol (this is commented out) variable from the GetCurrency method, but flash/actionscript doesn't seem to like the returning of values from the OnResult event.

How do I call this GetCurrency function so that once the function has completed, I have access to the result somehow??

```
<cfsavecontent variable="onLoad">
        <!--- Init --->
        _global.myResult;

        //create connection    
        var connection:mx.remoting.Connection = mx.remoting.NetServices.createGatewayConnection("http://<cfoutput>#cgi.HTTP_HOST#</cfoutput>/flashservices/gateway/");

        //declare service    
        var myService:mx.remoting.NetServiceProxy;
        var serviceName:String = '';

        var responseHandler = {};
        responseHandler.onStatus = function( stat: Object ):Void 
        {
           //if there is any error, show an alert 
           alert("Error while calling cfc:" + stat.description);
        }

        <!--- MyResult Get/Set --->
        _global.SetMyResult = function(result) 
        {
            _global.myResult = result;
            alert('_global.myResult' + _global.myResult)
        }       
        _global.GetMyResult = function() 
        {
            return _global.myResult;
        }

        <!--- Get Service Name --->
        _global.GetServiceName = function(serviceName) 
        {   
            var tServiceName:String = '';
            var tWebRoot:String = '<cfoutput>#Replace(Mid(request.site.webroot,2,Len(request.site.webroot)-1),'/','.','ALL')#</cfoutput>';

            <cfif request.site.webroot NEQ "">
                tServiceName = tWebRoot + '.' + + serviceName;
            </cfif>
            <!--- SALT --->
            tServiceName = 'pricelist.webroot.' + serviceName;

            return tServiceName;
        }       

        <!--- Get Currency --->
        _global.GetCurrency = function(currencyId)
        { 
            responseHandler.onResult = function( results: Object ):Void
            {
                var currencySymbol:String = '';

                if (results.length == 0) 
                {
                    alert('No details found!');
                } 
                else
                {
                    currencySymbol = results.getItemAt(0).currencySymbol;
                    _global.SetMyResult(currencySymbol);
                    alert('Symbol Before: ' + _global.GetMyResult());
                }
                //return currencySymbol;
            }           

            serviceName = _global.GetServiceName('components.currency');
            myService = connection.getService(serviceName, responseHandler );
            myService.getDetail(currencyId);
        }

        _global.GetCurrency('40346feb-feb9-11d8-995f-00c0df070000');
        alert('Symbol After: ' + _global.GetMyResult());
    </cfsavecontent>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ActionScript at all, but after defining your function you can assign it to a different scope:

```
<cffunction name="GetCustomDate">
    <!--- do stuff --->
</cffunction>
<cfset request.GetCustomDate = GetCustomDate>
```

So after doing that, your code would change as follows:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="OnCustomDateClick">
   var customdate = request.GetCustomDate();
   //do other stuff
</cfsavecontent>
<cfsavecontent variable="OnNewDateClick">
   var newdate = request.GetCustomDate();
   //do other stuff
</cfsavecontent>
```

Sorry if I didn't address your question appropriately - like I said, I am not familiar with ActionScript.

Ok, per your comment that will not work. Try defining your function like this:

```
_global.GetCustomDate = function() { /* do stuff here */ }
```

And calling it like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="OnCustomDateClick">
   var customdate = _global.GetCustomDate();
   //do other stuff
</cfsavecontent>
<cfsavecontent variable="OnNewDateClick">
   var newdate = _global.GetCustomDate();
   //do other stuff
</cfsavecontent>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that won't work. The code contained in the cfsavecontents is ActionScript, not cfscript. So you can not call the function like that.

Comment: Edited to offer another approach.

Comment: Thanks - that sent me in the right direction. I have implemented that in the OnLoad Event of the Form and so far everything is working correctly except for one thing. I have updated the post to reflect this issue. Can you offer any advice? Thanks

Comment: Glad that helped. I'm afraid that's about all I can assist with though - I know next to nothing about ActionScript. Good luck with the second half of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put your `GetCustomDate()` actionscript function in a `<cfformitem type="script">` before your cfsavecontents?

```
<cfformitem type="script">
function GetCustomDate():Date{
   // do stuff
}
</cfformitem>
```

Comment: @Fitzchev: Thanks - that approach also works. Please see my updated post for more details of the issue now. Thanks

Comment: @Cheeky for your last problem, I think that as the call is asynchronous your "global" variable _global.myResult has not been set yet when you're doing the alert RIGHT AFTER the remote call. Is "Symbol After" not displayed before "Symbol Before"?

Comment: @Fitzchev: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that is what's happening. It looks like the "Symbol After" is displayed first, followed by the "Symbol Before" which most likely confirms this. The question is, how to work around it?

Comment: @Cheeky it depends how and where you want to use _global.GetMyResult(). There's no point to do the second alert (Symbol After) as you have done... if you have some code that depend on the global variable _global.myResult then you have to put it "on hold" until the value is not null anymore.

Comment: @Cheeky you could also create a watchpoint: 
function myResultWatcher(property:String, oldvalue:String, newvalue:String):void
{
 if (_global.myResult != null) {
                             alert('Symbol After: ' + _global.GetMyResult()); 
                } 
}

this.watch("_global.myResult", myResultWatcher);

Comment: @Fitzchev: Yes, that's the problem. I DO have code that depends on the _global.myResult being set. Please could you provide more details on how to implement the myResultWatcher approach? I have tried using that code and it doesn't even compile. Is it meant for Actionscript 2 that Coldfusion uses? It's so frustrating because I know the value is set, but it always shows 'undefined'. I'm sure we are close. If you could perhaps illustrate what you mean by providing some code based on the code I updated above that would be great. Thanks

Comment: @Fitzchev: Ok, I have done some more testing and I have discovered where the problem lies. Anytime you try and call a global function from within the responseHandler.onResult() method you get unexpected results/variables not set. For example, if I create a simple function the way you illustrated initially:
`<cfformitem type="script">
function GetCustomString():String
{
return 'boboooo';
}
</cfformitem>`

If I call that function from anywhere EXCEPT within the responseHandler.onResult() method, I get the desired result. However, once I call it inside responseHandler.onResult(), I Get blank val?